# How to upload a file to the server on a button click in react app?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I have built a react application wherein I am rendering the home in the front page. Now I want to embed a file upload feature in the nav bar. So I added the button in public/index.html. I have a server and client side. Server is running on localhost:8000. Now if I want to upload a file into a particular path in the server let's say there is a folder in the server called as 'example-file'. How can I achieve this? Any help would be really appreciated. Attaching the index file and my project structure screenshot.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/fevicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>Config Genrator</title>
  </head>
  <body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100 bg-light">
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <nav
      class="navbar navbar-light"
      style="width: 100%;background-image: linear-gradient(to right,White,#333);"
    >
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img
          src="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo.png"
          width="162"
          height="39"
          class="d-inline-block align-top"
          alt=""
        />
      </a>
      <span class="navbar-brand text-white">
        Configuration Genrator
      </span>
      <input type="button" class="fas fa-file-upload" id="btnFileUpload" value="Upload File" />


    </nav>
    <div
      id="root"
      class="d-inline-flex align-self-center"
      style="width: 90%;"
    ></div>
    <footer style="width: 60%;" class="d-inline-flex align-self-center mt-auto">
      <p class="text-center" style="width: 100%;">©2020 </p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try using **multer** node module it helps you to upload file to a specific path to your server

Here is the link you can check how to use it:- [Resource for multer](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html) or [File upload with multer](https://medium.com/@svibhuti22/file-upload-with-multer-in-node-js-and-express-5bc76073419f)